# About the Lebesgue points of a product of functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

We say that a measurable function $g:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ has a *Lebesgue point* at $x \in \mathbb R$ if

$$ \frac1{2s}\int_{x-s}^{x+s} |g(y)-g(x)| \, dy \to 0 \quad \text{as } s \to 0.$$

If $g$ is continuous, then every $x \in \mathbb R$ is a Lebesgue point of $g$. The Lebesgue differentiation theorem states that a (locally) Lebesgue integrable function has Lebesgue points almost everywhere. The function given by

$$ g(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\chi_{(2^{-k-1},2^{-k}]} $$

is an example of a function that does not have a Lebesgue point at $0$.

Now suppose that $g: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ and $h: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ have Lebesgue points at every $x \in \mathbb R$. Is it possible that the product $gh$ has non-Lebesgue points?

Comment: Since $gh$ is not-necessary locally-integrable, the question does not make sense. (Take $h=g = \sqrt{x}^{-1}$, then $h$ and $g$ are locally-integrable, but not $gh$.)

Comment: @p4sch Note that $\sqrt{x}^{-1}$ does not have a Lebesgue point at $0$.

Comment: @mathworker21 If $g=h=0$, then $gh=0$ has a Lebesgue point at every $x \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: @cob hm I thought you had said "must $gh$ have non-Lebesgue points"

Comment: If $(q_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is an enumeration of $\mathbb{Q}$, we can define $h(x) = g(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n} (\max \{\sqrt{|q_n}|,1\})^{-1} \sqrt{|x-q_n|}^{-1}$. This function is locally-integrable, but $h\cdot g$ is not locally-integrable in any point of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @p4sch thanks for your comment. Could you please briefly explain why this function has Lebesgue points everywhere?

Comment: @p4sch it seems to me this choice of $g=h$ also doesn't give a Lebesgue point at zero.

Comment: Yes, we have only Lebesgue points almost everywhere!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $$g(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty 2^{k/2} \chi_{[2^{-k}-4^{-k},2^{-k}]}.$$ It is easy to see that every $x \neq 0$ is a Lebesgue point of $g$. At $x=0$ we have $$\frac1{2^{-n+1}}\int_{-2^{-n}}^{2^{-n}} |g(y)-g(0)| \, dy = 2^{n-1}\sum_{k=n}^\infty 2^{-3k/2} = 2^{-n/2-1}\sum_{k=0}^\infty 2^{-3k/2}$$ which goes to $0$ as $n \to \infty$. This also implies $$\frac1{2s}\int_{-s}^{s} |g(y)-g(0)| \, dy \to 0 \quad \text{as $s \to 0$}$$ and therefore $0$ is also a Lebesgue point of $g$.

However, $$g^2(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty 2^k \chi_{[2^{-k}-4^{-k},2^{-k}]}$$ does not have a Lebesgue point at $0$, which can be seen by adapting the exponents in the above calculation. In fact, $g^2$ does not have a Lebesgue point at $0$ even after redefining $g^2(0)$. Also note that $g^2$ is integrable at $0$.